# Json-Import of nodes with taxonomy terms

Tags: nodes, taxonomy-terms, 8

I'm running Drupal 8.3.6 and I try to import a json stream originating from typo3. It is essentially a list of blog posts in this format:

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Title",
    "bodytext": "Bodytext with html Mark-Up",
    "datetime": "1269437640",
    "keywords": "term1, term2, term3, term4,..."
},{
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Title 2",
    "bodytext": "Another Bodytext with html Mark-Up",
    "keywords": "term6, term3, term9, term7,..."
}]
```

I came up with a small module following [these instructions](https://jordanpagewhite.github.io/drupal-8-json-to-nodes/), which works well for the title and bodytext:

```
protected function createBlog(string $json) {
    $jsonout = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    foreach ($jsonout as $blog) {

      $node = Node::create(array(
        'type' => 'blog',
        'langcode' => 'de',
        'uid' => '1',
        'status' => 1,
        'title' => $blog['title'],
        'body' => ['value' => $blog['bodytext'], 'format' => 'full_html'],
      ));

      $node->save();
    }
  }
```

However I'm struggling to get the terms created and referenced by the nodes. I tried something like this, but it doesn't work:

```
protected function createBlog(string $json) {
    $jsonout = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    foreach ($jsonout as $blog) {
      foreach ($blog['keywords'] as $tag) { // Loop through each blog entries keywords and create terms
        $term = Term::create(array(
          'name' => $tag,
          'vid' => 'tags',
        ))->save();
      }

      $node = Node::create(array(
        'type' => 'blog',
        'langcode' => 'de',
        'uid' => '1',
        'status' => 1,
        'title' => $blog['title'],
        'field_tags' => $blog['keywords'], // I would need to have the terms from above in an array to add them here, right?
        'body' => ['value' => $blog['bodytext'], 'format' => 'full_html'],
      ));

      $node->save();
    }
  }
```

The terms do not get created and if they would, I wouldn't know how to associate them with the nodes. Also if it would work, there would be the problem that on creation of the terms I do not check if a term already exists. This would be necessary because nodes can have the same terms.

Is it possible to achieve this with my approach? If yes, can you tell me how? I also looked in to migrate_plus but I find it quite complicated.

Any help would be appreciated!

Andi

Comment: tl;dr. create migration.

Comment: I recommend using the Migrate API (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-api-overview) and the migrate_plus module (https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_plus) which provides a URL plugin, a JSON source, and an entity lookup process plugin that will look up taxonomy terms and store their ID with the node you're creating. This blog entry (https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2017/06/07/stop-waiting-for-feeds-module-how-to-import-remote-feeds-in-drupal-8/) was instrumental in helping me quickly grasp migrations.

Comment: @mounty Thanks for the link! I didn't come across before. It seems, that is exactly what I need to get it started!

Comment: I posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how the rest of your dependencies are set up, one thing I notice off the bat is that your `keywords` source field is a comma-separated single string, but you're treating it as an array of values in your processor. Maybe something like this:

```
protected function createBlog(string $json)
{
    $jsonout = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    foreach ($jsonout as $blog) {
        $newTags = explode(', ', $blog['keywords']);
        $newTagIDs = [];
        foreach ($newTags as $tag) {
            $newTagIDs[] = Term::create(array(
                'name' => $tag,
                'vid' => 'tags'
            ))->save();
        }

        $node = Node::create(array(
            'type' => 'blog',
            'langcode' => 'de',
            'uid' => '1',
            'status' => 1,
            'title' => $blog['title'],
            'field_tags' => $newTagIDs,
            'body' => ['value' => $blog['bodytext'], 'format' => 'full_html']
        ));

        $node->save();
    }
}
```

You're right that your approach would create multiple copies of the same term, though. The Entity Lookup plugin from the migrate_plus module might provide some help:

```
// $this->entityManager is a dependency-injected instance of Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityManagerInterface
$query = $this->entityManager->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
    ->getQuery()
    ->condition('name', $termNameToLookup)
    ->condition('vid', $vocabularyToLookup);
$results = $query->execute();
if (empty($results)) {
    // term doesn't exist in that vocabulary; should add it
} else {
    // the term already exists in that vocabulary; do something with it
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! However, I couldn't find out how to add multiple terms on node creation. `'field_tags' => $newTagIDs,` does not work. For a specific term it is: `'field_tags' => [
          ['target_id' => 277]
        ],` Also, I couldn't figure out how to check if a term already exists. I will digg into migrate_plus for a bit now.

Comment: Looks like you solved it via migration, but in the interest of not leaving this unanswered: I've actually never added multiple terms when using `Node::create()` so I assumed it would be just adding a flat array of tids. You could probably modify the for loop to create an array of arrays: `$newTagIDs[] = ['target_id' => Term::create(...)->save()];` But the migration is definitely the way to go here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mounty for pointing me to the tutorial of Campbell Vertesi to get me started with d8 migrate: https://ohthehugemanatee.org/blog/2017/06/07/stop-waiting-for-feeds-module-how-to-import-remote-feeds-in-drupal-8/

It's a blessing. Also the d8 docs are useful: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/migrate-process-overview

The crucial part to get my list of tags migrated is this pipeline:

```
field_tags:
    -
      plugin: explode
      source: keywords
      delimiter: ','
    -
      plugin: entity_generate
      lookupBundleKey: vid
      lookupBundle: tags
```

The explode plugin grabs the tags from the list and the entity_generate plugin checks if the entity exists. If not, the entity is created. The tags are then added to the node. The whole yml file for my import:

```
id: blog_importer
label: 'Blog Importer'
status: true

source:
  plugin: url
  data_fetcher_plugin: http
  urls: 'url/file.json'
  data_parser_plugin: json

  item_selector: blog-entry
  fields:
    -
      name: bid
      label: 'Blog Post ID'
      selector: uid
    -
      name: title
      label: Title
      selector: title
    -
      name: body
      label: Body
      selector: bodytext
    -
      name: keywords
      label: Keywords
      selector: keywords

  ids:
    bid:
      type: integer

destination:
  plugin: 'entity:node'

process:
  title: title
  'body/format':
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: "full_html"
  'body/value': body
  field_tags:
    -
      plugin: explode
      source: keywords
      delimiter: ','
    -
      plugin: entity_generate
      lookupBundleKey: vid
      lookupBundle: tags
  status:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  type:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: toppik_blog
```